# gRPC error : Unimplemented GenerateAll() method

Tags: makefile, protocol-buffers, grpc

I am trying to cross compile gRPC to ARM architecture.
I am on Ubuntu 14.04, i686-linux-gnu.
So, I downloaded the source on the gRPC's github repository.
Then I run (The directories in CPPFLAGS and LDFLAGS leads to cross-compiled third parties which I cross-compiled myself)

```
CPPFLAGS="-I/home/<my_name>/arm_third_parties/openssl-arm/install/include 
-I/home/<my_name>/arm_third_parties/zlib-1.2.8/install/include 
-I/home/<my_name>/arm_third_parties/protobuf_arm/install/include" 
LDFLAGS="-L/home/<my_name>/arm_third_parties/openssl-arm/install/lib 
-L/home/<my_name>/arm_third_parties/zlib-1.2.8/install/lib 
-L/home/<my_name>/arm_third_parties/protobuf_arm/install/lib" 
make 
CC=arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc HOST_CC=gcc 
CXX=arm-linux-gnueabi-g++ HOST_CXX=g++ 
LD=arm-linux-gnueabi-ld HOST_LD=ld 
LDXX=arm-linux-gnueabi-g++ HOST_LDXX=g++ 
AR=arm-linux-gnueabi-ar
```

But I get this error :

```
--grpc_out: Unimplemented GenerateAll() method.
```

With V=1 we can see the command line which is :

```
protoc -Ithird_party/protobuf/src -I. --grpc_out=/home/<my_name>/grpc_arm/gens --plugin=protoc-gen-grpc=/home/<my_name>/grpc_arm/bins/opt/grpc_cpp_plugin src/proto/grpc/testing/echo_messages.proto
```

It seems correct...

Do you know where does it come from ?

Thank you.